# Where can I get the machine readable API specification of the Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Where can I get the WADL/WSDL or just any machine readable specification of the Instagram API?

Comment: I have got the WADL from here. https://api.apigee.com/v1/consoles/instagram/apidescription?format=wadl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the WADL from [here](http://api.apigee.com/v1/consoles/instagram/apidescription?format=wadl).

The APIgee console has all the WADL of various API providers accessible in this way.